# Socket.io behind HAProxy behind Google Cloud load balancer giving connection errors

Tags: websocket, socket.io, google-cloud-platform, haproxy

We are trying to configure our Socket.io socket servers behind HAProxy and over HAProxy we are using Google Cloud Load Balancer, so that HAProxy is not the single point of failure. As mentioned in this post by https://medium.com/google-cloud/highly-available-websockets-on-google-cloud-c74b35ee20bc#.o6xxj5br8. Also depicted in the picture below.

[image]

At the Google cloud load balancer we are using TCP Load balancing with SSL Proxy with Proxy Protocol ON.

The HAProxy is configured to use Cookies so that a client always connects to the same server. However since cookies might not be available on all our clients system, we decided to use load balancing algorithm as `source` in HAProxy. Here is the HAProxy configuration

global
      log /dev/log    local0
      log /dev/log    local1 notice
      chroot /var/lib/haproxy
      stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
      stats timeout 30s
      maxconn 16384
      tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
      user haproxy
      group haproxy
      daemon

```
  # Default SSL material locations
  ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
  crt-base /etc/ssl/private

  # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
  # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
  #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
  ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
  mode http
  log global
  option httplog
  option  http-server-close
  option  dontlognull
  option  redispatch
  option  contstats
  retries 3
  backlog 10000
  timeout client          25s
  timeout connect          5s
  timeout server          25s
  timeout tunnel        3600s
  timeout http-keep-alive  1s
  timeout http-request    15s
  timeout queue           30s
  timeout tarpit          60s
  default-server inter 3s rise 2 fall 3
  option forwardfor


frontend public
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/key.pem ca-file /etc/ssl/private/cert.crt accept-proxy
  maxconn 50000
  default_backend ws

backend ws
  timeout check 5000
  option tcp-check
  option log-health-checks
  balance source
  cookie QUIZIZZ_WS_COOKIE insert indirect nocache
  server ws1 socket-server-1:4000 maxconn 4096 weight 10 check rise 1 fall 3 check cookie ws1 port 4000
  server ws2 socket-server-1:4001 maxconn 4096 weight 10 check rise 1 fall 3 check cookie ws2 port 4001
  server ws3 socket-server-2:4000 maxconn 4096 weight 10 check rise 1 fall 3 check cookie ws3 port 4000
  server ws4 socket-server-2:4001 maxconn 4096 weight 10 check rise 1 fall 3 check cookie ws4 port 4001
```

This is however giving connection errors on around 5% of our clients as compared to our old single server system. Any suggestions?

Edit: Connection errors means that the client was not able to connect to the socket server and the socket.io client was throwing connection errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "connection errors."  Does anything appear in the HAProxy logs correlating to these errors?

Comment: @sqlbot I see around 10% responses with code 400 in HAProxy stats